# How does this component render its children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am studying the code for [react-accessible-accordion](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/tree/master/src/components), and I don't understand how it renders its children.

From `Accordion.tsx`:

```
export default class Accordion extends React.Component<AccordionProps> {
    // ... defaults


    renderAccordion = (accordionContext: AccordionContext): JSX.Element => {
        const {
            preExpanded,
            allowMultipleExpanded,
            allowZeroExpanded,
            onChange,
            ...rest
        } = this.props;

        return <div data-accordion-component="Accordion" {...rest} />;
    };

    render(): JSX.Element {
        return (
            <Provider
                preExpanded={this.props.preExpanded}
                allowMultipleExpanded={this.props.allowMultipleExpanded}
                allowZeroExpanded={this.props.allowZeroExpanded}
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
            >
                <Consumer>{this.renderAccordion}</Consumer>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

This component accepts a few levels of nested children. Specifically, I don't understand how they are being passed down.

I can see that the component spreads the rest of props over a self-closing Accordion div element... How does that mechanism manage to render multiple levels of children?

Answer (score 1):

A React [context `Consumer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer) expects a function as its child to render the content. That function in this example is referenced as `this.renderAccordion`:

```
<Consumer>{this.renderAccordion}</Consumer>
```

Which renders the children in the `{...rest}` spread attributes:

```
        const {
            preExpanded,
            allowMultipleExpanded,
            allowZeroExpanded,
            onChange,
            ...rest
        } = this.props;

        return <div data-accordion-component="Accordion" {...rest} />;
```

The `...rest` includes `children` from `this.props` (and you can actually render children as an attribute, like `<div children={ <p>Hello!</p> } />`) from the destructuring assignment -- in other words `const { ...rest } = this.props` includes `this.props.children`.

Answer (score 0):

There is [`Provider`](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/blob/master/src/components/AccordionContext.tsx#L34) for providing and [`Consumer`](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/blob/master/src/components/AccordionContext.tsx#L102) for rendering the child components because the props are spread to the `Consumer` and `children` is a prop of `Accordian`.

[Here is the consumer being used](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/blob/master/src/components/Accordion.tsx#L48)

For individual components such as the [`AccordianItem`](https://github.com/springload/react-accessible-accordion/blob/master/src/components/AccordionItem.tsx), this uses `Provider` to define components which are meant to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAYiEMC8MAUBvGwAWBLAGwBMAnAUzBgF8BKFAPhgwCgYZyoBXEytVmAJAAeIngBu2EJzBRkGAIxVs-YuTBzchUhSUB6evxoBuZlRPNmoSLABCAQxIp0ABxIhnEOskYs2V6EyS0lAANDAAdJHkAUqoru4QJmz8HNy8_MKiEqDBcopMkeHRUHoGbMamRkA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=) may help you to understand.

Basically, when JSX is compiled to React code, it creates a component using:

- `React.createElement("div", null, children);`, or
- `React.createElement("div", { children }, null);`

Check how `Hello`, `Foo` and `Bar` component are compiled in the link that I sent you. Your case is gonna be the `Bar` component